# Could we have blue/violet shifting?

Tags: general-relativity, visible-light

As the universe expands, it stretches light into longer wavelengths, resulting in what we know as red shifting.

But some say that there is a chance in which the universe will stop expanding and then condense on itself.  Would this cause violet shifting?

Comment: Yes. (Which is too short to add as even a comment, actually.)

Comment: It can happen even due to Doppler effect. If a body comes towards the observer he observes blue shift.

Comment: It's not so much directly an expanding universe which causes redshift as it is the relative velocities between object and observer.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: If the Universe were static when a distant galaxy emitted light toward us, then expanded by a factor of, say, two before we received the light, and the became static again, we would still observe a redshift, even though emitter and receiver are static wrt. each both at the time of emission and detection.